# How to find and replace space between digits in a string column?

Tags: regex, pyspark, regexp-replace

I need to find and replace any space between digits in a long string using regular expression.

I have tried to use regular expression such as `[0-9][\s][0-9]` and then regexp_replace such as `.withColumn('free_text', regexp_replace('free_text', '[0-9][\s][0-9]', ''))`.
However, the regex matches `1(space)4` where I would like to have only `(space)`

Here is an example:

What I have:
`"Hello. I am Marie. My number is 768 990"`

What I would like to have:
`"Hello. I am Marie. My number is 768990"`

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do this, using capture groups:

```
.withColumn('free_text', regexp_replace('free_text', '([0-9])\s([0-9])', '$1$2'))
```

The idea here is to match *and* capture the two digits separated by a whitespace character in between them.  Then, we can replace by just the two digits adjacent.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern matches a digit, whitespace character and a digit. Note that `\s` also matches a newline.

If supported, you could use lookarounds instead of matching the digits:

```
(?<=[0-9])\s(?=[0-9])


.withColumn('free_text', regexp_replace('free_text', '(?<=[0-9])\s(?=[0-9])', ''))
```

Comment: Not sure if that function supports lookarounds. But looking at this page, the [regexp_extract](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract) function accepts a Java regex.